# Focal skin peeling on palms, fingerprints can be uncertain; will this be an issue for UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, health

I have cleared the interview for a software organization in Durham, UK and they have given me the COS (Certificate of sponsorship).

My doubt is I have a benign skin condition called [keratolysis exfoliativa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratolysis_exfoliativa), which means focal peeling of the palms, so my fingerprints may not be clear, except for 3 fingers.

I have all other documents and sponsorship from the company that hired me. 
Will this cause any problem in getting a UK visa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens on the immigration gate if a passenger lost their fingerprints?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90165/what-happens-on-the-immigration-gate-if-a-passenger-lost-their-fingerprints)

Comment: Do you have an e-Passport? Does it has fingerprints?

Comment: @user56513 I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is very generic.

Comment: Even though this question is much more detailed, I think the answers to that other question will be helpful. Even people without hands can travel.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, but if someone without hands shows up to a biometric appointment, obviously they won't have their fingerprints collected, and when they arrive in the UK, the border officer will not expect them to be provided. With this condition, it seems possible that a print could be recorded, but then there could be issues matching it in the UK. It seems to me that OP would like specific information about how he can make sure he isn't accused of traveling on someone else's visa.

Comment: I know that countries have lists what to do if a certain finger is not available for a print, which order of replacements. And at the end of that list is 'no fingers available'. So if OP can prove his fingers are not suitable, they will go on to those that do work. Likely a letter of a specialist doctor needed if finger sometimes look normal.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.